# Receiving notifications on upvotes, downvotes, and other reputation-related changes

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, android-app

I have been using the beta Stack Exchange official app for three days. The notification system is amazing. I receive a new comment and my phone vibrates instantly! Just gorgeous! Now I know whenever I'm mentioned, or if someone posted a comment to me.

But I miss a feature: **Notifications for reputation changes**

All know what I'm talking about: We are aaaaalways checking for reputation changes, and would be amazing if we receive phone notifications when someone upvote/downvote our questions or if someone has accepted our answers. Just like in the achievements tab recently added to the web client.

So: **Are reputation notifications listed on the app roadmap, or there is a problem of implementing that?**

As we commented, this feature should come with specific notifications settings, to allow us to disable/enable certain common notifications. I'm not someone who receives one upvote per minute, but there are some folks on the SE network (Yes John Skeet, I'm talking about you...) who could consider phone reputation notifications a completely mess, just a continuous vibration of their phone.

Comment: I feel like I wouldn't want this, or if it was implemented it would need to be separated from the other notifications and toggle-able in the settings. Otherwise posting a popular answer would make your phone notify you almost nonstop. Plus, for users who have been around a while, it's pretty common to have a steady trickle of votes on older posts every day, and I don't care enough to be constantly notified of these.

Comment: @eldarerathis of course receiving different kind of notifications (Specially with multiple notifications per minute things like upvotes and downvotes) should have different settings, and should allow you to disable the different kind of notifications separately.

Comment: @Marc-Andre I have mentioned it  in the question.

Comment: @Manu343726 My bad

Comment: I miss this from Droidstack. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.droidstack&hl=en