# Cannot review a close vote item even though I can vote to close it, if I previously cast a vote and it aged away long ago

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

I just got [this review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/40560) in the close queue, and was surprised to see "This item is not reviewable":

> [image]

Going to the question at stake, I noticed [this comment of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218519/receiving-notifications-on-upvotes-downvotes-and-other-reputation-related-chan#comment804150_218519) which means I have cast a close vote in the past, which is long expired now.

However, since last March we can [recast expired close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting), so I successfully cast it via the ordinary channels: (not review)

> [image]

Can this be fixed so that we can close via the review queue?

Comment: Does this still continue to be an issue today?

Comment: @Sonic hard to reproduce now with hammer my close votes as dupe can't really age away, and the rest are as off topic and the questions always get closed and deleted. But I'll try, thanks for reminding me to check it.

Comment: It's still an issue for close *flags* which aged away (and you gain the close vote privilege later).